# Unusual behavior in Python and R

Tags: python, r

I am working with some data that contains a column identifying the price brack for which a product belongs, and I have noticed, both in R and python a weird behavior:

```
# R
d <- c('5-10', '20+', '15-20', '10-15', '0-5')
sort(d)

[1] "0-5"   "10-15" "15-20" "20+"   "5-10"

# Python

d = ['0-5', '10-15', '15-20', '20+', '5-10']
sorted(d)

>>> ['0-5', '10-15', '15-20', '20+', '5-10']
```

Besides, of course, the fact that I would like to find a solution to correctly sort this array, my question is: why this behavior?

Comment: Because when you sort strings, it uses alphabetical sorting rules, and `5` > `2`.

Comment: @Randy is correct.  The sort is behaving correctly, if not as you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks, I have found exactly the same behavior in Node.js as well.

Answer (score 1):

in **R** try

```
stringr::str_sort(d, numeric = TRUE)
[1] "0-5"   "5-10"  "10-15" "15-20" "20+"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, string sorting uses alphabetical sorting rules. If you want to treat these as numbers, you can add some logic to `sorted` 's `key` argument to do some cleanup on each and sort them as numbers:

```
In [34]: sorted(d, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0].replace('+', '')))
Out[34]: ['0-5', '5-10', '10-15', '15-20', '20+']
```

Comment: Funny that it's the first time I see that the solution in python requires more code than the one in R. Thanks!